# Puppet upstart issue: Error: /Service[ssh]: Provider upstart is not functional on this host

Tags: ubuntu, service, puppet, upstart

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04LTS on several hosts configuring using puppet. The hosts are identical. One day on some hosts puppet agent started to not recognize upstart services. I'm receiving `Error: /Service[servicename]: Provider upstart is not functional on this host`. The services are 100% under upstart. There is no such issue on other hosts.

Tried puppet agent versions: 3.4.3, 3.7.3

What the problem is?

Here is the trace:

```
$ puppet resource service ssh ensure=running provider=upstart --debug
Debug: Runtime environment: puppet_version=3.7.3, ruby_version=1.9.3, run_mode=user, default_encoding=UTF-8
Debug: Puppet::Type::Service::ProviderOpenrc: file /bin/rc-status does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Service::ProviderUpstart: 0 confines (of 2) were true
Debug: Puppet::Type::Service::ProviderDaemontools: file /usr/bin/svc does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Service::ProviderRunit: file /usr/bin/sv does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Service::ProviderLaunchd: file /bin/launchctl does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Service::ProviderRedhat: file /sbin/chkconfig does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Service::ProviderGentoo: file /sbin/rc-update does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Service::ProviderSystemd: file systemctl does not exist
Debug: Loaded state in 0.00 seconds
Debug: Puppet::Type::Service::ProviderUpstart: 0 confines (of 2) were true
Error: /Service[ssh]: Provider upstart is not functional on this host
Debug: Finishing transaction 21131160
Debug: Storing state
Debug: Stored state in 0.00 seconds
Debug: Puppet::Type::Service::ProviderUpstart: 0 confines (of 2) were true
Error: Could not run: Provider upstart is not functional on this host
```

UPDATE:

```
$ /sbin/status ssh
ssh start/running, process 2789

$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.1 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

Comment: can you manually run `/sbin/status ssh` and `cat /etc/os-release`, what's the output?

Comment: looks fine, the last try I will do is , restart the host and try again. :-)

Comment: What's the output of `facter operatingsystem` and `facter operatingsystemrelease` ?

Comment: @FelixFrank `Ubuntu` and `14.04`

Comment: That [should work](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/7bdcbea51284b47b2cada15b5f55381fd2dc4815/lib/puppet/provider/service/upstart.rb#L14-17) so something is strange. Can you launch `irb` and do `require 'puppet' ; puts Facter.value(:operatingsystem)` ?